# Preserved sauces

Tags: food-safety

I'm making my own alfredo sauce and want to know how I can preserve it so I can store it in the fridge or in the freezer for longer periods of time. I also have a chilli sauce with no meat that I need to preserve? Lastly I have a vodka sauce with cream, tomato sauce, and prosciutto I need to preserve.

Comment: AFAIK, nothing special is required for long term freezing... what do you mean by long term refrigeration?

Comment: Cream sauces if freezed will seperate. a preserve that will keep the sauces from spoiling. I heard of lecithin but never used it.

Comment: I mean length of time... How long do you want to be able to preserve them in the fridge.

Comment: Considering [this answer](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/60444/preserving-eggnog/60481#60481), I don't think that there's any home-process way to indefinitely preserve dairy products. Canning dairy requires industrial processing.

Comment: closing, as the OP never clarified if it is about keeping the sauce frozen or in the refrigerator.

Answer (score 0):

Food borne bacteria will not grow very well, if at all, below 40F. So you can freeze the food for long periods of time (up to 6 months or more), eat it, and be safe.

The issue you will run into with freezing that long is quality. As time passes, the food will get "freezer burn" which destroys the quality of the food. A solution for this is vacuum sealing your food before freezing. This will give you good results including long lasting quality.